# CSS: Select multiple classes' child

Tags: css, refactoring

I want to select multiple parents' child in CSS in this manner:

```
(.parent1, .parent2, ...) > child {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way I can do this without duplicating code:

```
.parent1 > child,
.parent2 > child,
... {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would say you have to duplicate code anyway even if the parent element don't matter so you can just simply style `.child` directly.

Comment: Never(!) use CSS, only LESS or SCSS files, then you can do that and many more, while maintaining CSS syntax. All you need is a "compiler" but there are many extensions. Thank me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:is()` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

```
:is(.parent1, .parent2, ...) > child {
    ...
}
```